# Is that possible to dynamically add a web source client to Icecast?

Tags: icecast

I would like to build a web app to process an audio stream broadcasted by an Icecast server and send the processed stream back to the Icecast server.

The idea is that this stream becomes a new source client for the Icecast server.

I have two questions:

- is there any web source client that allows to send a stream from a browser to an Icecast server?
- is that possible to dynamically add this source client to the Icecast server?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are no Icecast web source clients.

And yes it is possible to dynamically add source clients, since having a `<mount>` section is generally not required, only if advanced mountpoint configuration is used. So just point the source client to an unused mountpoint location and use the general source password and the username `source` to identify.